# Laravel 8 - Could not find driver : Illuminate\Database\QueryException could not find driver (SQL: select * from `list`)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, crud, laravel-8

I have installed Laravel 8 on my Linux Mint 20 for my personal experiment so I'm new on Laravel's new version. I've searching many source how to show tables with CRUD method so the table is shown in the web with contains data from MySQL database

But when i tried to show table with CRUD method, it appeared like this :

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException
> could not find driver (SQL: select * from `list`)

in localhost:8000/home/tabel

I tried to solving this problem from repairing .env file, Controller file, blade file, and the web.php to be correct but it still error.

And this is my configuration file which i've change like this :

.env

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=people
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

homeController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class homeController extends Controller
{
    public function home()
    {
        return "home";
    }

    public function tabel()
    {
        $tabelku = DB::table('list')->get();
        return view('tabel', ['people' => $tabelku]);
    }

}
```

tabel.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <title>Table</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div align="center">
            <table border = "1">
                <tr>
                    <th>No</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Age</th>
                    <th>Hobby</th>
                </tr>

                @foreach($tabelku as $t)
                <tr>
                    <th>{{$t->no}}</th>
                    <th>{{$t->name}}</th>
                    <th>{{$t->age}}</th>
                    <th>{{$t->hobby}}</th>
                </tr>
                @endforeach
            </table>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

and then web.php

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::get('/hello', function () {
    return 'Halo Dunia';
});

Route::get('/home','homeController@home');

Route::get('/home/tabel','homeController@tabel');
```

And this is database and table which i use to show tables from CRUD method -> [image]

For MySQL database i use XAMPP

Can anyone explain why this is error and give me solution what should I do to repair this?

Comment: "could not find driver" means that PHP cannot find the mysql / pdo_mysql extension. You have to enabled it in the `php.ini`

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Just install appropriate driver for PHP-MySQL:

```
# default
sudo apt install php-mysql
# for specific version of php (e.g. php7.4)
sudo apt install php7.4-mysql
```

Restart your server:

```
# apache
sudo systemctl restart apache2
# nginx
sudo systemctl restart nginx
```

Comment: Finally it works after i install PHP-MySQL so "could not find driver error" is not anymore. But now I still cannot showing table because there is an new error : Illuminate\Database\QueryException
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory (SQL: select * from `list`). Can you give me solution what should I do to repair this? (still in same code)

Comment: please try with DB_HOST=127.0.0.1 instead of DB_HOST=localhost  and after that change don't forget to refresh the caches (php artisan config:cache)

Comment: ok, it works and "No such file or directory" error is not anymore, and then when I tried to refresh, there is an new error again : ErrorException
Undefined variable: tabelku (View: /opt/lampp/htdocs/isidata/resources/views/tabel.blade.php) in http://localhost:8000/home/tabel. Can you give me solution what should I do to repair this? (still in same code in homeController.php, tabel.blade.php and web.php)

Comment: in your controller replace 'people' to 'tabelku'

Comment: yes, it works. finally the table is show and no more errors again. Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

This is for the users who are using shared hosting where SSH facility may not be available.

Go to your Cpanel PHP settings, and make sure the following features (especially PHP 8.0 or above) are enabled.

mysqli
pdo mysql

Because laravel's "DB" and "Models" in controllers need these features enabled. Otherwise the controller will raise the DRIVER NOT FOUND exception.

Answer (score 0):

Clear Cache: Sometimes, cache issues can cause unexpected errors. Run the following commands in your Laravel project's root directory:

php artisan config:clear

and

php artisan cache:clear

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This did seem to help in my case. Although it may have just been restarting the app server that fixed it.