# Illuminate\Database\QueryException No version available – Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, exception

I've recently come into a company and setup error tracking and this error is coming up multiple times a day:

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException
No version available(SQL: select `Id`, `OwnerId...)
```

Nothing comes up when searching for this error and it's something that no one seems to have heard of...

Any ideas?

Comment: which version of php you are using?

Comment: I think this is your answer please check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66600266/laravel-8-could-not-find-driver-illuminate-database-queryexception-could-not