# Is there a reason I am getting this Backpack DevTools error?

Tags: laravel-backpack

I am getting the following error after running the backpack devtools install.

`php artisan backpack:devtools:install`

I'm unsure about the warning above. My env is set to local.
Now the DevTools menu item appears and when I click it I get the following exception:

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException
could not find driver (SQL: create table "models" ("file" varchar, "id" integer not null primary key autoincrement, "file_type" varchar, "file_extension" varchar, "file_path" varchar, "file_path_absolute" varchar, "file_path_relative" varchar, "file_path_from_base" varchar, "file_name" varchar, "file_name_without_extension" varchar, "file_name_with_extension" varchar, "file_last_accessed_at" datetime, "file_last_changed_at" datetime, "file_last_modified_at" datetime, "file_created_at" datetime, "file_directory" varchar, "file_contents" varchar, "class_name" varchar, "class_namespace" varchar, "class_path" varchar, "class_path_with_extension" varchar, "created_at" datetime, "updated_at" datetime))
```

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66601024/10573560

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you do not have SQLite installed - or the sqlite extension is not enabled in your php.ini

Backpack uses Laravel Sushi, which itself uses SQLite to store all the information about Models etc.

Comment: Thanks, lead me back to the site where i read the troubleshooting guide again and low and behold :D

https://backpackforlaravel.com/products/devtools/readme.md

Comment: Specifically devtools requires sqlite from i could tell